# how to count the letters in each letter in a string in Java?

Tags: java, count, split, words

I have used this code to try this out:

```
String st="Hello world have a nice day";
String arr=st.Split(" ");
for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    ???
}
```

But it doesn't work.

I want it to output something like this:

```
Hello=5
World=5
have=4
a=1
nice=4
day=3
```

Does anyone know the right code, please?

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like this:

```
String[] words = yourString.split(" ");

for (String word : words) {
  System.out.println(word + " length is: " + word.length());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`word.length()` returns the length of a String.

However, the `split()` method will just split the String by spaces, leaving everything in the resulting splits. By everything I mean punctuation, tabulators, newline characters, etc, and all those will be counted towards the length. So instead of just doing `word.length()`, you might want to do something like:

`word.replaceAll("\p{Punct}", "").trim().length()`.

- `replaceAll("\p{Punct}", "")` removes all punctuation marks from the
  String.
- `trim()` removes all leading and trailing whitespaces.

So for example, a sentence:

> I saw a will-o'-the-wisp.\n

(`\n` means the end of line character, which you might get if you read the String from a file, for example).

The sentence will split to:

```
"I"  
"saw"  
"a"  
"will-o'-the-wisp.\n"
```

the last string

> will-o'-the-wisp.\n

has 18 characters, but that's more than the character count in the word. After the `replaceAll()` method, the string will look like:

> willothewisp\n

and after the `trim()` method, the string will look like:

> willothewisp

which has length 12, the length of the word.

Answer (score 0):

Use an enhanced for loop and print out the word and its length.

```
foreach(String w : st.split()) {
    System.out.println(w + ": " + w.length());
}
```