# JAVA: Count each word on a String, and count each letter on the words

Tags: java, string, tokenize

So, I've got a java assignment in which I have a String with a phrase. I need to count each word the phrase has and then count how many letters each word has. I've been able to split the phrase into words by using the Tokenizer, and then count and print the amount of words with .countTokens(). However, I'm not being able to count the letters in each word.

Basically the output should be something like this:

> "Nihil veritas est"
>   Words: 3
>   Nihil: 5 letters
>   Veritas: 7 letters
>   Est: 3 letters

Here's my code so far:

```
public class words {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type a phrase.");
    String phrase= in.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer stoken = new StringTokenizer(phrase);
    System.out.println("Your phrase has "+stoken.countTokens()+"words");


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15317778/how-to-count-the-letters-in-each-word-in-a-string-java?rq=1

Comment: You're off to a good start. What have you tried so far to print out each word that the Tokenizer finds? From there, counting letters will be easy.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use the `split()` method instead?

Comment: Not so far. I would have to iterate over the token, right?

Comment: Ok, I was just asking. I've never used `StringTokenizer` before. What do you mean by "iterate over the token"?

Comment: Hmmm I haven't tried with `split()`, but I'll look over it.

Comment: Sorry there, that was in answer to ProgrammerDan. 
I mean to go over the `StringTokenizer`with a loop so it prints each words the tokenizer founds.

Comment: @AndrésAvilaWille I see. No worries, next time try using `@username` to reply to someone specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class words {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please type a phrase.");
        String phrase= in.nextLine();

        String[] words = phrase.split(" ");

        System.out.println("The number of words is:"+words.length);

        for(int i=0; i<words.length; i++){
            System.out.println(words[i]+" is "+words[i].length()+" letters long.");

        }
    }
}
```

This code uses `split()` instead of `Tokenizer`. It just seemed easier to me.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. Only one small thing, `words.length()` should be `words.length`. `words[i].length()` is correct though.

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you. I didn't try with `split()` because I couldn't quite understand how to use it. Not only did you helped me with the exercise, but now I understand how to use the `split()`.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to be of some help.

Comment: The only remaining risk factor is that split(" ") splits on a single space.  So (" A "+" B").split(" ") returns an array with 4 elements.  To be a little more bulletproof, use (" A "+" B").trim().split("\\s+"). I'm using string addition to get around the fact that the double-space is getting reformatted by the forum code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCount {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("PLease enter your phrase");

    String phrase = in.nextLine();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(phrase);
    System.out.println("Your phrase has " + st.countTokens() + " words");
    // Loop thorough to count number of letters in each word.
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String tokenName = st.nextToken();
        System.out.println(tokenName + ": has  " + tokenName.length() + " letters");
    }

 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know how to do it with the tokenizer as well. My doubts are all clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type a phrase.");
    String phrase= in.nextLine();

    // get an array each having a word using split
    String[]words = phrase.split(" ");

    //print count of words?
    System.out.println("Words: "+words.length);

    //loop over the words
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(words[i]+": "+words[i].length()+" letters");
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class wordCount 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(" Enter a String1");
    String str=sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(" Entered String : ");
    System.out.println(str);
    //logic
    char ch[]=str.toCharArray();
    str="";
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.length; i++) 
    {
        if(ch[i]!=' ')
        {
            str=str+ch[i];
            count++;
        }
        else if(ch[i-1]!=' ')
        {
            /*str=str+"-->"+count +" ";*/
            System.out.println(str+"--->"+count);
            count=0;
            str="";
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str+"--->"+count);

sc.close();
    }
}
```